# Removing jQuery default easing

Tags: jquery, easing

I am using .animate() to animate my picture gallery.But when I use the hide function it puts its own easing effect which is undesirable since I want a linear easing. I tried the following but its not working.

```
$(picArray[picArrayIndex - 1]).hide( '500','linear',function(){
    $(picArray[picArrayIndex]).show();
     });
```

Any way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(picArray[picArrayIndex - 1]).hide({duration : 500, easing : 'linear', complete: function(){your things}})
```

Here's the list of option you can use : http://api.jquery.com/hide/#hide-options

Answer (score 1):

put '0' as first parameter which means that the animation won't be visible.
The 'linear' is needless as you don't want any animation.

```
   $(picArray[picArrayIndex - 1]).hide(0, function(){
        $(picArray[picArrayIndex]).show();
    });
```

Comment: thanks man,but just out of curiosity,is 0 the animation opacity or sometihn

Comment: the first param is the duration. Set to 0 means that there won't be an animation.

Comment: This answer is achieving what you ask, this should be mark as the correct answer @ParthMody

Comment: @MarianoArgañaraz `easing` and `duration` are 2 different things. As the question state : *"Disabling jQuery **easing** completely"*.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Those are indeed different things. But if you remove easing COMPLETELY then you have no ease function anymore (not even linear) and hence no timespan which results in having a duration of 0.

Comment: @sjkm Well, I don't think op will ever come back here so no point arguing. But since my answer is accepted, he probably just wanted a linear easing (since it is not the default value). Also, why would he use a duration + a callback if he did not want an animation?

Comment: @karl-andré-gagnon You are rigth, I think the question is wrong. I'be sent an edit for review based on user's chosen answer.